# Laravel how to validate two request inputs againt single column in form request

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I am working with laravel 9.1. I want to validate two request inputs in single column of a table. below is my validation rule in form request.

Basically `name = resource_name . permission_type` i thought of merging both column before the validation but the problem is both fields needs to be validated first before concatination.

Can anyone please help me how do i validate `resource_name` and `permission_type` first and then check for `resource_name.permission_type` in the `name` column `permission_types` table.

Thankyou.

```
$name = $this->request->input('resource_name') . '.' . $this->request->input('permission_type');
$this->request->merge([
    'name' => $name,
]);

return [
    'type' => ['required'],
    'resource_name' => ['required', 'alpha', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
    'permission_type' => ['required'],
    'name' => ''
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what i did. the `name` field is an actual field in the database but its data is coming from two different inputs i.e `resource_name` and `permission_type` if the field is not present in request the rules won't get triggered and applied, so i create a hidden input type with permission_name in view. and created a custom validator which does the job.

`<input type="hidden" name="permission_name" value="" />`
FORM REQUEST:

```
$rules = [
    'resource_type' => ['required'],
    'resource_name' => ['required', 'alpha', 'min:3', 'max:50', new IsPlural],
    'permission_type_name_single' => ['required'],
    'permission_name' => new UniqueTwoInputsInOneColumn('permissions', 'name', $this->request->get('resource_name'), $this->request->get('permission_type_name_single'))
];
```

CUSTOM RULE:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Rules;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    class UniqueTwoInputsInOneColumn implements Rule
    {
        protected $tableName;
        protected $columnName;
        protected $value1;
        protected $value2;
        protected $ignoreField;
        protected $ignoreFieldValue;
        
        /**
         * Create a new rule instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct($tableName, $columnName, $value1, $value2, $ignoreField = null, $ignoreFieldValue = null)
        {
            $this->tableName = $tableName;
            $this->columnName = $columnName;
            $this->value1 = $value1;
            $this->value2 = $value2;
            $this->ignoreField = $ignoreField;
            $this->ignoreFieldValue = $ignoreFieldValue;
        }
        
        /**
         * Determine if the validation rule passes.
         *
         * @param string $attribute
         * @param mixed $value
         * @return bool
         */
        public function passes($attribute, $value)
        {
            if (!$this->ignoreField)
            {
                return DB::table($this->tableName)->where($this->columnName, $this->value1 . '.' . $this->value2)->count() == 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return DB::table($this->tableName)->where($this->columnName, $this->value1 . '.' . $this->value2)->where($this->ignoreField, '!=', $this->ignoreFieldValue)->count() == 0;
            }
        }
        
        /**
         * Get the validation error message.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function message()
        {
            return 'The Permission name ' . $this->value1 . '.' . $this->value2 . ' already exists.';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $name = $request->validate([
        'type' => ['required'],
        'resource_name' => ['required'],
        'permission_type' => ['required'],
        'name' => [
            $request->input('resource_name'). '.' .$request->input('permission_type')
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: i appreciate your effort but this did'nt work for me. I came up with my own solution

Answer (score -1):

Add this code :

```
     $validatedData = $request->validate([


     'resource_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:3', 'max:255'],



     'permission_type' => ['required'],
     ]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).